# Swiss Canton Level Data Request on unemployment and social spending

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am interested in finding Swiss canton-level data on unemployment and public spending. Where could I find this?

Comment: Please expand your question. For example, are you interested in current unemployment, or historical? And are you interested in cantonal  or federal public spending related to unemployment, or just public spending? Please see [here](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/a/285/1511) about asking a good question

Comment: My apologies, since I mention canton-level data I assumed it was obvious that the unemployment and public spending data should be for the cantons.

Comment: *public spending* on what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a reference on public spending,  but the unemployment data is available from the [Swiss Federation](https://www.amstat.ch/v2/download.jsp?lang=de).   You will need to speak one of French, German or Italian. Use the pull down menu to select a year and monthly data is available. Use the long version (on the left).