# Unemployment Data

Tags: data-request, demographics

Where can I find data about unemployment data (any country) as well as other economic data, e.g. Gross domestic product, Living wage and etc.

In Russia I find only 15 rows of data. I cant build a model based on this data to complete my goal of developing a model for forecasting unemployment.

Comment: see here for swiss data http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/10537/1511

Answer (score 2):

Many countries have their own labor statistics published through a dedicated agency, such as the [US Bureau of Labor and Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/data/#unemployment) or the [Swiss Federation](https://www.amstat.ch/v2/download.jsp?lang=de). Unemployment is also an indicator you can examine on the [World Bank's Data Portal](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator?tab=all) which provides global analyses of various indicators by country. Some of the other indicators you mentioned are also searchable on the World Bank site and each graph is accompanied by source information to help find the original data used in that particular visualization.

For a wider repository of global labor data (cited as the source for some of the World Bank data above) you can find that on the [International Labour Organization's web site](http://www.ilo.org/global/statistics-and-databases/lang--en/index.htm). Their database, [ILOSTAT](http://www.ilo.org/ilostat) has extensive aggregate data on global employment broken out by country, age, gender, and population density.

Comment: Data on OECD countries and the EU are publicly available at http://stats.oecd.org/.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to head over to the [Bureau of Labor and Statistics](https://www.bls.gov/data/#unemployment). The page for unemployment data is [here](https://www.bls.gov/data/#unemployment).